# Nant <nant> task in quiet mode?

Tags: nant

I want to use the <nant> task in my build script but I want the task to run in quiet mode.  I want the main script to run in normal mode.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but as far as I know it does not allow you to make it silent.

From a build perspective though if you were to try and make it silent and one of your nested builds failed you would not know what caused the build failure.

Disk space is cheap and log files are small so I'd say letter rip.  Actually in build setups we have we actually increase the verbosity so that we can get as detailed a build log as possible.  It has helped several times when things went haywire (usually due to people not checking things in).